# Magento 2.2.4 issue with module version

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, error, upgrade, magento2.2.4

I downloaded the project from bitbucket and extracted files in that and imported database.

I flushed cache.
Deployed static content.
Run upgrade command.
Run compilation and moved to production.

I face below error.

```
The following modules are outdated:
Magento_Directory db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.1, currently installed - 2.0.2
Magento_Directory db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.1, currently installed - 2.0.2
Magento_Customer db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.12, currently installed - 2.0.13
Magento_Customer db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.12, currently installed - 2.0.13
Magento_Catalog db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.2.3, currently installed - 2.2.4
Magento_Catalog db data version: defined in codebase - 2.2.3, currently installed - 2.2.4
Magento_Quote db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.6, currently installed - 2.0.7
Magento_Quote db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.6, currently installed - 2.0.7
Magento_Sales db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.7, currently installed - 2.0.9
Magento_Sales db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.7, currently installed - 2.0.9
Magento_Newsletter db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.0, currently installed - 2.0.1
Magento_Newsletter db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.0, currently installed - 2.0.1
Magento_Vault db schema version: defined in codebase - 2.0.2, currently installed - 2.0.3
Magento_Vault db data version: defined in codebase - 2.0.2, currently installed - 2.0.3
WeltPixel_Backend db schema version: defined in codebase - 1.0.3, currently installed - 1.1.0
WeltPixel_Backend db data version: defined in codebase - 1.0.3, currently installed - 1.1.0
```

Comment: In database check the setup_module table, I guess the schema_version & data_version are not matching, or mismatching

Comment: On local, I did the same before and it was working and on the server, the same issue arises. Anyways I chose server because after solving this I face new error. 1) Static contents start from frontend and not from pub/static 2) Home page is loading and other pages are not blank. Shows null body tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely you have been working on this project before and already have a database in place which apparently has newer versions of the modules you're trying to use.

The current versions of the modules don't match the ones already stored in `setup_module`.

Possible solutions:

- Update the version of each module in `setup_module` to the one defined in the codebase (i.e. `Magento_Directory` to 2.0.1)
- Delete the entries for these modules in `setup_module` and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade` again to create the new entries with the correct version

Comment: On local, I did the same before and it was working and on the server, the same issue arises. Anyways I chose server because after solving this I face new error.
1) Static contents start from frontend and not from pub/static
2)  Home page is loading and other pages are not blank. Shows null body tag.